# React Navigation: is it safe to call `navigation.popToTop()` and `navigation.navigate('route')` back to back?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

We have an app that often needs to navigate between screens in different navigators. In some scenarios, we need to navigate away from a screen in a stack navigator to a different navigator. In doing so, we need to make sure that the stack we're leaving is reset to its initial screen (popToTop). We accomplish that with code like this:

```
const onExit = () => {
    navigation.popToTop();
    navigation.navigate('routeName');
}
```

This code works, but is it considered safe? Is there any chance that the component would unmount before `navigation.navigate('routeName')` is called, or does React Navigation somehow "queue up" navigation actions before the screen unmounts?

This code always seems to work, but is it considered a good practice? Why or why not?